# Admin is messed up within windows 10 (fresh format and installation). Must always right click and select run as admin

Tags: windows, administrator

I have a weird issue i have had for weeks now and i give up i need help figuring this out. So randomly my windows 10 Build 1809 started doing nothing when opening apps that need admin, i have to right click and select run as admin. Sometimes depending of the file it still may not run for example if its a packed rar sfx installer. i also cannot open archives with winrar i get the error "no archives found" however 7zip works fine.

I noticed when apps work after the right click run as admin, in task manager is does not display the full exe name it displays with a ~ for example temaviewer.exe would become TEAMVI~.EXE I run a few scripts upon installation of windows but nothing that should mess up or change anything to do with the user accounts or admin access.

When going to change my environment variables under the username options in control panel the USERNAME variable says "SYSTEM".

I have reformatted multiple times and even rolled back to previous versions of windows 10 and tried on vms and other machines after a reboot or 2 this keeps happening. however the laptop im on now is running the same version of windows 10 and the same scripts and works totally fine.

Please can somebody help me im going out of my mind here. Its very hard to use my computer as things just do not work correctly.